# ayuda con funcion en php y jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, login

hola resulta que tengo lo siguiente:

```
    $("#frmAcceso").on('submit',function(e)
{    
    e.preventDefault();
    logina=$("#logina").val();
    clavea=$("#clavea").val();

    if ((logina!="") && (clavea !=""))
    {                
         $.post("../Ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar",
            {"logina":logina,"clavea":clavea},
            function(data)
        {           
            alert(data.length);
            alert(data);

            if ((rpsta=="null") || (rpsta==null))
            {               
                //$(location).attr("href","Categoria.php"); 
                bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");           
            }
            else
            {
                //bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");
                $(location).attr("href","Categoria.php"); 
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#logina").focus();
        swal('Oops...','Proporcione todos los datos','error');        
    }

})
```

y un método php que hace lo siguiente

```
case 'verificar':

            $logina=$_POST['logina'];
            $clavea=$_POST['clavea'];

            $clavehash=hash("SHA256",$clavea);

            $rspta=$usuario->verificar($logina, $clavehash);            

            $fetch=$rspta->fetch_object();  


            if(isset($fetch))
                {                   
                    $_SESSION['idUsuario']=$fetch->idUsuario;                   
                    $_SESSION['Nombre']=$fetch->Nombre;
                    $_SESSION['Imagen']=$fetch->Imagen;
                    $_SESSION['Login']=$fetch->Login;
                }

            echo json_encode($fetch);
        break;
```

ahora bien lo que hace la función verificar  es ver si el usuario esta registrado en la base de datos.

```
public function verificar($login,$clave)
        {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Login='$login' AND clave='$clave' AND Condicion='1'";                     
            return EjecutarConsulta($sql);
        }
```

ahora el problema es que cuando valido si la consulta me devuelve un dato

```
if ((logina!="") && (clavea !=""))
    {                
         $.post("../Ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar",
            {"logina":logina,"clavea":clavea},
            function(data)
        {           
            alert(data.length);
            alert(data);

            if ((rpsta=="null") || (rpsta==null))
            {               
                //$(location).attr("href","Categoria.php"); 
                bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");           
            }
            else
            {
                //bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");
                $(location).attr("href","Categoria.php"); 
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#logina").focus();
        swal('Oops...','Proporcione todos los datos','error');        
    }
```

aunque me regrese null me direcciona a la pagina de categoria.php

le comento que la pagina al tengo montada en un servidor nas DS216J personal

mucas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: En jQuery, estás comparando con un valor que no existe: `if ((rpsta=="null") || (rpsta==null))` ¿de dónde sacas `rpsta`?  Tienes que obtener  el valor que quieres comparar de la respuesta del servidor, que se encontrará en la variable `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si estas devolviendo a **rpsta** desde el php en json, debes coger esa variable desde la despuesta data dentro del callback, pero al parecer lo que devuelves no es el rspta, si no los valores de **$fetch**, quedando data con esos valores.

seria algo como:

```
 $.post("../Ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar",
            {"logina":logina,"clavea":clavea},
            function(data)
        {           
            alert(data.length);
            alert(data);

            if (data.length === 0 )
            {               
                //$(location).attr("href","Categoria.php"); 
                bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");           
            }
            else
            {//sesion exitosa}
```

o puedes ver si data en null

```
       $.post("../Ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar",
            {"logina":logina,"clavea":clavea},
            function(data)
        {           
            alert(data.length);
            alert(data);

            if (data)
            {               
                //sesion exitosa           
            }
            else
            {

                bootbox.alert("Usuario y/o Password incorrectos");
}
```

> INSTALA EL MOZILLA DE DESARROLLADOR Y AYUDATE CON FIREBUG PARA VER LA
>   RESPUESTA COMO ES Y AHI SABER COMO USARLA

Comment: Que tal amigos ya llevo tiempo con esto y no me funciona el resultado de la función ya me devuelve null pero aun así no valida el if (valuser == 4)
            //if(data!="null")
            //if(data)    
            {  
                $("#logina").focus();
                swal('Oops...','Usuario o contraseña incorrectos','error');                      
            }  
            else
            {
                $(location).attr("href","Categoria.php");                                                                         
            }

Comment: PUEDE MOSTRAR IMAGEN DE LO QUE DEVUELVE?

Comment: @ANDRESFERNANDOMARTINEZVALEN si tienes nueva informacion, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la informacion ahi.

Answer (score -1):

e.preventDefault();
logina=$("#logina").val();
clavea=$("#clavea").val()`introducir el código aquí`;

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../admin/ajax/usuario.php?op=verificar',
    dataType: "json",
    data:{"logina":logina,"clavea":clavea},
    success:function(data){
        if(data){
            $(location).attr("href","escritorio.php"); 
        }
        else{
            bootbox.alert("usuario o password incorrecto");
        }
    }
});
```

})

Comment: Tu respuesta no explica cual fue el error del OP. Tampoco explica por qué esta es la solución. Es sólo un trozo de código sin contexto ni explicación. ¿Por qué funciona? ¿Dónde lo pongo? ¿Qué hice mal?